# Getting ZipException when trying to open a jar file

Tags: jar

[image]

I have an jar file. I want to see the contents of that jar file, but when I try to unzip that file I am getting an error like **java.util.ZipException: error opening zip file**.
 I used the command ***jar tvf jar_file_name *** in command prompt.
I think that file is password protected or something else. Is there any way to open that file so that I can see the contents.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the file is just *broken* - for example, you may have fetched it by FTP in text mode, instead of binary, or if you downloaded it programmatically you may have a bug in your download code.

As a quick test, try renaming it to a zip file and open it with WinZip or whatever your favourite zip file client is. That will confirm whether or not it's really bust.

I don't believe there's any such thing as a password-protected jar file.

Comment: Actually that jar file is an mobile application and its runs well in my mobile. So can I see the contents in computer.

Comment: @Debabratta: What kind of mobile application? It could be that this is a special form of jar file, specific to this sort of platform. What's the *exact* and complete error? Include the whole stack trace. Did you try renaming the file to `foo.zip` and then opening it as I suggested?

Comment: It is an executable jar file. The mobile version of my        UC Browser running in my Nokia handset and I am trying to open it in windows machine.

Comment: Yes I tried to open that jar file by Winrar but it showing corrupt file.

Comment: @Debabratta: I suspect that the jar files used by Nokia devices don't follow the exact same format as regular jar files then.